# Unable to use type string as sql.NullString

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am creating a `gorm` model

```golang
// Day is a corresponding day entry
type Day struct {
    gorm.Model
    Dateday   string         `json:"dateday" gorm:"type:date;NOT NULL"`
    Nameday   string         `json:"nameday" gorm:"type:varchar(100);NOT NULL"`
    Something sql.NullString `json:"salad"`
    Holyday   bool           `json:"holyday"`
}
```

I am using `sql.NullString` for the field `Something` cause it may be NULL.

So when I try to execute a typical `gorm` example to validate my setup works:

```
    db.Create(&Day{
        Nameday:     "Monday",
        Dateday:     "23-10-2019",
        Something:   "a string goes here",
        Holyday:      false,
    })
```

I get:

> cannot use "a string goes here", (type string) as type sql.NullString in field value

What type should I use for the `Something` field given it may be NULL?

Comment: `sql.NullString` is a `struct` type and is not convertible to a `string` type. You need to initialize a value of `sql.NullString` and set that to the field. One way to do that would be `Something: sql.NullString{String: "a string goes here", Valid: true}`. https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond; I would suggest you post it as a normal answer so I can accept / upvote it

Comment: If I remember correctly you can use `*string` type for `NULL`-able columns

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`sql.NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) type is not actually a string type but a struct type. It's defined as:

```
type NullString struct {
    String string
    Valid  bool // Valid is true if String is not NULL
}
```

Therefore you need to initialize it as such:

```
db.Create(&Day{
    Nameday:     "Monday",
    Dateday:     "23-10-2019",
    Something:   sql.NullString{String: "a string goes here", Valid: true},
    Holyday:     false,
})
```

---

As an alternative, if you *want* to keep using the simpler syntax when initializing a nullable string, you could declare your own nullable string type, have it implement the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces, and leverage the null byte to signal a `NULL` value.

```
type MyString string

const MyStringNull MyString = "\x00"

// implements driver.Valuer, will be invoked automatically when written to the db
func (s MyString) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if s == MyStringNull {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return []byte(s), nil
}

// implements sql.Scanner, will be invoked automatically when read from the db
func (s *MyString) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        *s = MyString(v)
    case []byte:
        *s = MyString(v)
    case nil:
        *s = MyStringNull
    }
    return nil
}
```

With this, if you declare the field `Something` to be of type `MyString` you can initialize it as you originally intended.

```
db.Create(&Day{
    Nameday:     "Monday",
    Dateday:     "23-10-2019",
    // here the string expression is an *untyped* string constant
    // that will be implicitly converted to MyString because
    // both `string` and `MyString` have the same *underlying* type.
    Something:   "a string goes here",
    Holyday:     false,
})
```

Just keep in mind that this works only with untyped constants, once you have a constant or variable of type `string`, to be able to assign that to a `MyString` you'll need to use an explicit conversion.

```
var s string
var ms MyString

s = "a string goes here"
ms = s // won't compile because s is not an untyped constant
ms = MyString(s) // you have to explicitly convert
```

Comment: Something:   sql.NullString{String: "a string goes here", Valid: true}, worked out for me, thank you.

Comment: Really nice answer. A small typo in `Scan` function. It should return `MyStringNull` in case of `nil`, and not `StringNull`. Too small of an edit so SO doesn't allow me to suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/guregu/null"
)

func main() {

    db.Create(&Day{
        Nameday: null.StringFrom("Monday"),
    })
}
```