# nil does not set database record to NULL

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm, and I have a nullable column `gender` which can be set either `male` or `female`, but I am not able to set it back to `NULL` using `nil` once the column is set with a value of either `male` or `female`

The following is my code. To simplify things a bit, I only include the fields related to my question

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    Username    string       `gorm:"type:varchar(40);unique" json:"username"`
    NickName    string       `gorm:"type:varchar(32)" json:"nickname"`
    Gender      *string      `gorm:"type:enum('male', 'female');default:null" json:"gender"`
}
```

and then I update my gender to male:

```
db.Model(&User{}).Where(&User{
    Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1},
}).Update(
    &User{
        Gender:   utils.GetStringPtr("female"),
        NickName: "nick name",
    },
)
```

and then I tried to update the gender to NULL

```
db.Model(&User{}).Where(&User{
    Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1},
}).Update(
    &User{
        Gender:   nil,
        NickName: "nick name",
    },
)
```

However, the gender stays the same `female`, and it is **NOT** changed to `NULL`.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: do you want to prevent from setting `null` ? or you can`t set null?

Comment: @ttrasn, I can't set it to null, I would like to know how I can set it back to NULL

Answer (score 3):

from the official doc, I found this
http://gorm.io/docs/update.html

```
// Update multiple attributes with `struct`, will only update those changed & non blank fields
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18})
//// UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;

// WARNING when update with struct, GORM will only update those fields that with non blank value
// For below Update, nothing will be updated as "", 0, false are blank values of their types
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "", Age: 0, Actived: false})
```

If I do:

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{"gender": nil})
```

this can successfully updates the model column to NULL.

However, I realized this is kinda bad, because if I set a bool column to `True`, that means I will never be able to set it back to `False` using struct update. Is there any way to work around this ? What is the design purpose of this.

Comment: I suggest you to prevent from using `interface{}`. Its not best solution for your code.

Comment: However according to doc, the zero value will not be updated using struct update, what is the best practice here?

Comment: see ttrasn's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433706/5902688

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`null package`](https://github.com/guregu/null).

for example :

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    Username    string       `gorm:"type:varchar(40);unique" json:"username"`
    NickName    string       `gorm:"type:varchar(32)" json:"nickname"`
    Gender      null.String  `gorm:"type:enum('male', 'female');default:null" json:"gender"`
}
```

then for set element to null you must do this :

```
gender := null.StringFromPtr(nil)
```

from your code, you must do this:

```
db.Model(&User{}).Where(&User{
    Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1},
}).Update(
    &User{
        Gender:   null.StringFromPtr(nil),
        NickName: "nick name",
    },
)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, I updated my gender field to exactly you suggested, and tried to set gender to NULL by using `gender := null.StringFromPtr(nil)`, gender still **not** getting updated

Comment: I am using:
`github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.15`
`gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4 v4.0.0`
`go version go1.14.7 darwin/amd64`

Answer (score 0):

Use [sql.Nullstring](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString)

example: [Unable to use type string as sql.NullString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792313/unable-to-use-type-string-as-sql-nullstring)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32246565)

Comment: Good to have: If you can add example.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with the `Updates` command of GORM. If you configure it correctly, in the best case scenario you will have an empty string in the DB.

**You need to use the `Save` method of GORM in order to store NULL in your DB.**

If you are working on an API, this is a **PUT** method not a **PATCH**.

You also don't need an extra package for the struct. You can use

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    Username  string         `gorm:"type:varchar(40);unique" json:"username"`
    NickName  string         `gorm:"type:varchar(32)" json:"nickname"`
    Gender    sql.NullString `gorm:"type:enum('male', 'female');default:null" json:"gender"`
}
```

and have a function to transform the string to sql.NullString

```
func StringToSQLNullString(s string) sql.NullString {
    if s != "" {
        return sql.NullString{
            String: s,
            Valid:  true,
        }
    }
    return sql.NullString{}
}
```

In the end, you need to get your **User** from DB, to keep the CreatedAt property and then save it. Your code will be like this (For null, you don't need the gender)

```
updatedUser := &User{
  ID: 1,
  NickName: "nick name",
}

existingUser := &User{}
_ = db.First(existingUser, updatedUser.ID).Error

updatedUser.CreatedAt = existingUser.CreatedAt

_ = db.Save(updatedUser).Error
```

Including the gender, the struct is like this

```
updatedUser := &User{
  ID: 1,
  NickName: "nick name",
  Gender: StringToSQLNullString("male")
}
```

EDIT

Else, if you only want to update the gender your own answer is the way

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{"gender": nil})
```